# Memory Consumption by Java Applet

Tags: java

In my applet I have GET call to download file from a remote location. When I am trying to download some large file of around 13MB, then my Applet memory consumption is increasing more than 50MB. I am using the below code to get my memory consumption:

```
public static long getMemoryUsage()
{
    long memory = 0;
    // Get the Java runtime
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    return memory;
}
```

Code for my get call is

```
public  void getFiles(String filePath, long fileSize)throws MyException
    {
        InputStream objInputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try 
        {
            URL fileUrl=new URL(filePath);
            final String strAPICall=fileUrl.getPath();
            final String strHost="some.test.com";
            final int iPort=1000;
            URL url = null;
            url = new java.net.URL
                        ( "https",
                                strHost, iPort , "/" + strAPICall,
                                new myHandler() );  

            conn = (HttpURLConnection)new HttpsURLConn(url);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.connect();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {

                objInputStream=conn.getInputStream();

                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (objInputStream)));

                String output;
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);

                }
                throw new MyException("Bad response from server", 
                            MyError.BAD_RESPONSE_ERROR);

            }
            else
            {

                notifyProgressToObservers(0);
                System.out.println("conn.getResponseCode()"+conn.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println("conn.getResponseMessage()"+conn.getResponseMessage());
                objInputStream  = conn.getInputStream();
                int count=objInputStream.available();

                System.out.println("Stream size: "+count);
                System.out.println("fileSize size: "+fileSize);
                byte []downloadedData = getBytesFromInputStream
                        (objInputStream, count,fileSize);
                notifyChunkToObservers(downloadedData);
                notifyIndivisualFileEndToObservers(true, null);

            }

        }
        catch (MyException pm)
        {
            throw new MyException
            (pm, MyError.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        }
        catch (IOException pm)
        {
            throw new MyException
            (pm, MyError.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

            notifyIndivisualFileEndToObservers(false,new MyException(e.toString()));
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Closing all the streams after getting file");
            if(conn !=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
            if(objInputStream != null)
            {
                try {
                    objInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
            if (br != null) 
            {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

In the above method, I tried putting the log for memory consumption after each line and found that after `conn.connect();`, the memory consumption of applet increases by atleast 50MB even though the file I am trying to download is only 13MB.

Is there any memory leak anywhere?

**EDIT: Added Implementation for getBytesFromInputStream()**

```
public byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is, int len, long fileSize)
            throws IOException 
    {
        byte[] readBytes= new byte[8192];
        ByteArrayOutputStream getBytes= new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int numRead = 0;

        while ((numRead = is.read(readBytes)) != -1) {
            getBytes.write(readBytes, 0, numRead);
        } 


        return getBytes.toByteArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because of this line:

```
 byte []downloadedData = getBytesFromInputStream(objInputStream, count,fileSize);
```

here you are reading the complete amount of bytes of file into the heap. After that you need to track down what happens with this array. Maybe you are copying it somewhere and the GC needs some time to kick in even if you do not use the reference to the object anymore.

Large files should never be read completly to memory, but rather streamed directly to some processor of the data.

Comment: And if that method uses ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray, it reserves the 13M twice (and also the arrays that are allocated when the internal buffer is grown as it runs out of space). Wouldn't be surprised if it hits 50M just from loading the data before GC is run.

Comment: Up to 3 times, because `ByteArrayOutputStream` doubles the side of its internal buffer whenever it needs to grow.  So the buffer can be up to 2 times too big.   Then allow for the churn due to reallocating, and the process can easily consume > 50GB for a 13GB file.

Comment: @StephenC, I added the implementation for getBytesFromInputStream(), Can you suggest me how I can optimize it decrease memory consumption.

Comment: Well, nice theory but in reality there are cases where loading an entire file can be unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to optimize `getBytesFromInputStream()` is if you know beforehand *exactly* how many by bytes there are to read.  Then you allocate a `byte[]` of the required size, and read from the input directly into the `byte[]`.   For example:

```
  byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
  int pos = 0;
  while (pos < len) {
     int nosRead = is.read(buffer, pos, len - pos);
     if (nosRead == -1) {
         throw new IOException("incomplete response");
     }
     pos += nosRead;
  }
  return buffer;
```

(For more information, read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-).)

Unfortunately, your (apparent) attempt at getting the size is incorrect.

```
  int count = objInputStream.available();
```

This doesn't return the total number of bytes that can be read from the stream.  It returns the number of bytes that can be read *right now* without the possibility of blocking.

If the server is setting the `Content-Length` header in the response, then you could use that; call `getContentLength()` (or `getContentLengthLong()` in other use-cases) once you have the response.  But be prepared for the case where that gives you `-1`.

Comment: The above solution has reduced the memory consumption by few MB. For example the same 13MB file is now consuming around 43MB. Do you see any other possible optimization? I still don't know why 13MB file is consuming almost 3 times the memory.

Comment: You need to provide an MCVE.